# Check if a email came with powershell

Tags: powershell, email, exchange-server

I have a application where I need to check daily to verify that I received a email from a certain address, with specific data in the subject line. If it can't find the email I want it to send a email to IT so we can trouble shoot the problem. I would like to be able to run this verification process once a day automatically. I thought this is something I should be able to do with Power Shell. Note our email server is Exchange 2012.

Comment: This is not a do-your-work website.  Show some effort.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it:

1. Need access to the mailbox that receive those emails, so you can search it.
2. Need a schedule task to look for a specific email,subject,sender etc.
3. Once you get that done you can easily filter out the needed result and add logic to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you search the Message tracking logs https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124926(v=exchg.160).aspx eg use a Date and MessageSubject and sender filter to specify the criteria you want to search for and that should do it.